# Include ViewCount in the Posts table for tag wikis (in SEDE)

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, tag-wiki

[Currently, the `ViewCount` column of the `Posts` table in SEDE is always null for tag wikis (posts where `PostTypeId = 4`).](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/265574/viewcount-isnt-populated-for-tag-wikis)

But this data is certainly tracked somewhere internally - I can look at the [python tag wiki on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) and see that it has been viewed 35,714 times. It would be nice if this information could be included in SEDE for tag wiki posts.

Motivation: knowing which tag wikis are being read tells us something about which ones need to be the most carefully maintained; which ones are probably most useful to users; whether anybody even reads the damn things at all; etc. Obviously, the view count on tag wikis is going to correlate pretty strongly with the number of questions in the tag, but that's all the more reason that this data would be useful - to identify cases where the ratio of views to posts is anomalously high or low.