# View counts on tag wikis aren't monotonically increasing?

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, views

I posted [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247154/224428) on 16 Jan 2015, which happened to mention that the [python tag wiki on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) had been viewed 35,714 times.

Now that I look at it on 21 Jan 2015, I see that it has only been viewed 35,409 times:

[image: python tag wiki sidebar on SO]

Of course, it's not possible to unview a tag wiki, so the view count should never decrease.

This might be just a me-being-stupid issue rather than a bug - I might have mistranscribed the viewcount in the 16 Jan post. But I've made this post in case it really is a bug, because this is an issue that SE employees are more capable of investigating/reproducing than me (I don't know how I'd go about trying to reproduce the bug besides randomly clicking on tag wikis and hoping to see the view counts drop).

Comment: Oh, all those people that must be screaming "screenshot or it didn't happen" right now...

Comment: Could this be the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134748/179419? Chrome was over-enthusiastically caching pages. Are you on Chrome? What version?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I am on Chrome (41.0.2272.12, Windows), but I don't think that could be the issue here - even if I open up the python tag wiki in IE (which I almost never use), it still reads as having 35,480 views (which is less than 35,714). More likely is that this is just a PEBKAC issue and I'm bad at reading numbers.